# M1: Remove "?___store=default" from the URL

Tags: magento-1.9

I've tried most of the solutions to remove "?___store=default" from magento URL but no success.

that makes duplicates for every page on magento (1.9.4) site that effecting SEO.

is there a working solution for this issue?

Comment: Magento 1.9.4 is not out yet. Do you mean Magento 1.9.2.4?

Answer (score 3):

The parameter is necessary if multiple store views have the same base URL because to distinguish on what store view you are, a cookie must be used. This cookie is set based on the `___store` URL parameter.

If your store views have different base URLs (like different domains or subdirectories, also possible with the configuration *Add Store Code To URLs*), you *could* try to set up a 301 redirect using `.htaccess` that redirects these URLs to the same URL without `___store` parameter.

But there is a caveat: you absolutely **need** the `__from_store` parameter if you use different URL keys in different store views. It is used to look up the URL path in this store to find the product or category, then redirect to the URL in the selected store. On product and category pages, this is not a SEO issue, because of the redirect, but on other pages it does nothing and if you remove `___from_store` from all URLs, the redirect won't work anymore.

An alternative is to implement what Magento Enterprise does out of the box (I can't give code details for obvious reasons):

A predispatch observer that looks for the `___store` and `___from_store` parameters, figures out what's the right URL and redirects while setting the store cookie.

Answer (score 2):

In **System -> Configuration -> Web -> URL Options** the first item is 'Add Shop Code to URLs'. That will be set to **'No'** by default. Of course, anyone seeing this will assume that having that set to **'No'** means that the '?___store=' part shouldn't be appended to the url, but the opposite is the case. That parameter is used by Magento to display the correct store because it’s set to **'No'**, not in spite of it.

Comment: You should mention that setting this configuration to "Yes" results in URLs like `example.com/de` where `de` is the store code (i.e. the store code is always part of the base url). It's true that as a side effect it also removes the `___store` parameter because it is not necessary anymore.

Comment: I'm using a single store so why is that required? also when I enabled that option my site return 404 error

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do anything about such URL. Instead, you login your Google Webmaster and go to the section "URL parameters". In this section you can add the ?___store parameter and let Google know that it doesn't affect page content.

Answer (score 0):

If, like us, you already have these URLs indexed by Google, you should exclude them in [URL parameters](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/crawl-url-parameters), ensure you have a [canonical URL tag](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=en) and then you could also intercept the request in something like index.php and 301 it to a page without the unwanted params:

```
$url = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
if (!empty($url['query'])) {

    //$params = arrary();
    $checkingfor = array('___store', '___from_store');
    parse_str($url['query'], $params);
    if (count(array_intersect_key(array_flip($checkingfor), $params)) > 0) {
        $vars = array_diff_key($params, array_flip($checkingfor));
        $finalUrl = http_build_url(
            '',
            array(
                "scheme" => $_SERVER['REQUEST_SCHEME'],
                "host" => $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'],
                "path" => $url['path'],
                "query" => http_build_query($vars)
            )
        );
        header('Location: ' . $finalUrl, true, 301);
        exit();
    }
}
```

If you don't have PECL installed, use [this alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7753154) to http_build_url().

Originally [posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63426407/1439760).