# Removing ?___store=default from the url

Tags: magento-1.9, url, url-rewrite

I'm trying to remove the ?___store=default from the url of a page of my Magento store. I tried pretty much all the solutions including changing the .htaccess. How do I do this?

I've tried adding a redirect to my htaccess and changing the 'Add Shop Code to URLs' to **Yes** in **System -> Configuration -> Web -> URL options**

Comment: What exactly did you try? And where does this URL parameter appear where you don't want it? Please update your question with details, otherwise it is not possible to give a useful answre.

Comment: try this once : http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/127358/m1-remove-store-default-from-the-url/127363  , also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27267597/force-removal-of-store-code-store-default-from-url-s-in-magento

Comment: I've tried adding a redirect to my htaccess and changing the 'Add Shop Code to URLs' to Yes in **System -> Configuration -> Web -> URL options**

Comment: @BabyinMagento I've tried these, but they don't work. A 301 redirect doesn't work because of the question mark. I also tried this one and that doesn't work either:
`RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \?___store=default
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1? [L,R=301]`

Comment: as `fschmengler` said , please update what and all you tried in question.....